# Why does Worf want O'Brien to go to Minsk?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, worf

I've just watched the last 20 minutes of an episode of Deep Space 9, and towards the end Worf is very insistent that O'Brien and his wife move to Minsk. Is there any in or out of universe reason for this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If I remember this that is in the last episode, or very near the end of the show. O'Brien had gotten a position teaching at the Academy (on Earth) and Worf, having [lived on Earth](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Worf#The_Rozhenkos) for part of his life, may have lived in or near Minsk, or at least close enough to the Ural mountains to go camping there occasionally.

> The Rozhenko family eventually moved to Earth, where Sergey frequently took Nikolai and Worf camping in the Ural Mountains.

Worf being very insistent is just his way (watch the TNG episode where he tries to get his son to clean his room and eat his dinner).

Comment: Or at least in the vicinity of it, such that he visited there from time to time.

Comment: Memory alpha/beta conflicts on this point...

Comment: @Pureferret hmm, I'll need to check that when I get home. Can you link to what is conflicting?

Comment: How is Minsk in Russia?

Comment: @bitmask More than one city can have the same name. Happens all the time in the States. [Minsk, Russia](http://g.co/maps/4syje)

Comment: Even the Minsk in Belarus was under Russian rule until 1990, after the end of TNG.  So during TNG, calling Minsk part of Russia would have been accurate.  But not by the time of DS9

Comment: Calling that region a city is a bit far fetched. There are at best 100 inhabitants in the Minsk, Russia you linked. I doubt it even existed 15 years ago.

Comment: Regardless. Besides which, after the third world war who is to say that the Minsk most people think of isn't part of Russia, and continues to be through to when Worf is a child?

Comment: Considering how many times cities in that part of the world have changed their country affiliation within my own relatively-short lifetime, I don't want to make any predictions about whether it'll be considered Russia in the 24th century. For all we know, in Worf's childhood, all of Eurasia is considered "Russia" just like how huge portions of the US Eastern seaboard are considered "New York."

Comment: The Ural Mountains are no where near Minsk....

Comment: @Pureferret Well, they are considerably closer to Minsk than to Detroit. Besides, when you have ubiquitous transporters and shuttle craft what does distance matter?

Comment: Belarus has been part of the Polish and Russian Empires in the past.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - the Kimberley is also nowhere near Adelaide - but people take their kids camping there... camping in the Urals doesn't preclude living in Minsk

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - true, but keep in mind that on the Earth of that century, travelling anywhere on the globe takes only minutes because of teleporters, and only slightly more time by shuttlecraft.

Comment: here is a related question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13537/has-worf-ever-been-to-minsk?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 5):

It was clearly established (in the various EU novels) that Worf's adopted parents, after leaving the Earth colony on Gault, had **retired to a small farmholding *in Minsk***. Worf traveled with them and spent some time there prior to joining Starfleet. Evidently he grew to like the city and its environs.

> *When **Helena Rozhenko opened the door of her modest farmhouse in Minsk**,
> she let out a girlish squeal of delight that did not remotely seem to
> match her exterior as she saw Worf standing in the doorway. She threw
> her arms around him before he was able to get a word out, and as
> courageous as the Klingon was, he had to admit he felt safer in the
> elderly woman's embrace. "Sergey!" she cried out, summoning her
> husband. "Worf, why didn't you tell us you were coming ... ?"*
>
> <sub><sup>[Triangle: Imzadi II](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Triangle:_Imzadi_II)</sup></sub>

and

> *Zelik had been hearing stories about the Rozhenkos’ Klingon boy all of his life. The farming community on Gault was a very close-knit one. **While the Rozhenkos had retired to Minsk on Earth by the time Leybenzon was a teenager,** the stories about them lingered. Not all those stories were pleasant ones. Worf had accidentally caused the death of a fellow teenager during a soccer game.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek: Q&A](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Q%26A)</sup></sub>

Comment: Evidently referring to [Minsk Region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minsk_Region) rather than the capital city [Minsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minsk).